# Search the internet for plant species using Google search-by-image API

Tags: java, android, google-api

I'm thinking about developing an Android app which is capable of searching plant species by photographing it and letting Google's search-by-image API compare the image to those in Google's image database to find out which species it is and outputting information about it.

Is there any possibility to use that API for it and if not, are there actually possibilities for image comparison with Google?

Comment: Updated tags to remove unnecessary tags and removed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google ended their support for the search by image API. So unfortunately, that is no longer available. You can however, try using someone else's API but they usually are not free and do not have as big of a database as google

Became deprecated in 2011: https://developers.google.com/image-search/

Perhaps a little more information from a previous post: [Google reverse image search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997597/google-reverse-image-search-api)

Answer (score 0):

This API is deprecated since 2011.

> The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited.
>
> **We encourage you to use the Custom Search API, which now supports image search.**